# MVC Identity Cookie Security best practices for localhost developing and deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I have multiple ASP MVC projects on my computer, and, each one of them uses the identity framework along with various controllers that have the `[Authorize]` attribute.

I find that if I log in with one project, then, debug another on localhost, I can bypass the security in the other projects.

I understand that this is because there is just one cookie for localhost, but, is there any easy way to get around this for debugging purposes, and, is there any security concerns when deploying to the public internet?

Comment: When configuring authentication, make sure each project specifies a different `CookieName` value.

Comment: @TiesonT.- I don't have a problem with my cookies, I have a problem with the default authentication cookies which I can't rename. In addition, as I said, if I can login to different apps with users that don't exist in that project, I am curious to know about best practices for deploying to the internet...

Comment: Why would you not be able to change the name of the authentication cookie? That's always been part of FormsAuthentication, and OWIN is no different. If all you are doing is applying the AuthorizeAttribute (with no roles or claims) it's only checking if an auth cookie exists, not that it originated from the current application

Comment: Hi @TiesonT.- sorry, I missed this and just revisiting a few things. The main point I was trying to get at wasn't about renaming - it was that I don't understand why I can have a new app, login to get authenticated then create a completely new unrelated app, but, if the cookie has the same name, it keeps me logged in. So, what is stopping me from copying the content of the cookie, then pasting it to a different cookie no matter the name bypassing authentication. I know/feel that there is more to it and this shouldn't be possible - but, I don't understand why it works on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

As @TiesonT says you need to rename authentication cookie for each of your applications. You can do it in `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // other properties
    CookieName = "MyCookieName",
});
```

Alternatively you can set up your applications on your dev machine in IIS and give them each own domain name through hosts file. I.e. `MyApplication.dev`, `MyOtherApplication.dev`

Answer (score 0):

The cookies ASP.NET generates for authentication are encrypted, so not just any code can read the cookie values. If you haven't changed any of the default settings in the various web projects, then they are all using the same name, and (**when run locally**) being encrypted with the same keys. You can avoid this by

- (a) giving each site a unique cookie name and
- (b) adding a unique [machine key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx) to each site (assuming this isn't a .NET Core app).

Even just doing (b) would keep the various sites from reading each other's cookie, although then you'd be dealing with exceptions, since every site that didn't create the cookie would try and fail to decrypt the cookie.

Without a machine key, ASP.NET uses automatically-generated keys for encryption and decryption of things like the auth token and viewstate values; as long as each site has it's own app pool, you *should* not see auth cookies being shared across sites. You see shared auth sessions locally because you're running a single instance of Cassini/IIS.

I built a [simple site](http://machinekeyapp.com/) for generating machineKey pairs (should probably move it to HTTPS at some point), or you can use the code from it's [Github project](https://github.com/tiesont/machinekey-generator) to generate your keys locally.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the ~2 year delay! Glad you are still around here! :) Ok, so, the Cookie Name is just a tiny part and prevents overlap on the same dev environment. The real thing here is the machine key. I now understand (at last) why this is happening, but, It still feels weird to me that I can create a user on App A which doesn't exist on App B, switch to App B and the authentication just gets bypassed / no state table/info that either the session or cookie isn't real, or just plain validation that the user exists... it feels like a security hole, but, I guess I'm alone there!

Comment: The authentication cookie isn't necessarily linked to a user - it's just the info that ASP.NET needs to create a Principle on the current thread. All the AuthorizeAttribute does (by default) is assert that: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs

Comment: "Old school" implementations would be tied to Membership, so if you implemented those providers, yeah, it *should* verify the user (and/or role(s)) exists, but that doesn't happen with the modern project templates, especially if you're using the Identity framework.

Comment: You have to remember that the AuthorizeAttribute is just for **authorization**. It doesn't concern itself (nor should it) with **authentication**.

Comment: Ok, your last comment makes perfect sense!... Is there any easy to understand/use/integrate authentication based frameworks that tie in with identity well? (p.s. would upvote, but I don't have enough points... I'm on here very rarely!) And thanks!